# Laravel conditions in Controller where clause

Tags: php, if-statement, laravel, conditional-statements, clause

I'm trying to build a query based on URL parameters.  When the Controller is loaded I need to check which parameters have been provided and build a query from them.  It's working with static values, but isn't working with conditional statements.  Is my laravel syntax correct?

```
class OrdenesController extends BaseController {

public function showOrdenes($action)
{
  $my_id = Auth::user()->id;
  $my_cod = Auth::user()->codprov;

  switch ($action) 
  {
    case 'list':
      $rows = DB::table('ordens')->count();
      if(Input::get("jtSorting"))
      {
       $search = explode(" ", Input::get("jtSorting"));            
       $numorden= Input::get("nro_orden");
       $filtros =explode(" ", $filtros);

       $data = DB::table("ordens")
        ->select(array('*', DB::raw('SUM(cant_pend) as cant_pend'), DB::raw('SUM(importe) as importe')))
        ->where('cod_prov', '=', $my_cod)

        ->where('nro_orden', '=', $numorden)///work

        ---------- ////no work
        if (Input::has('nro_orden')) {
           ->where('nro_orden', '=', $numorden)
        }
        ---------- /// no work

        ->groupBy('nro_orden')
        ->skip(Input::get("jtStartIndex"))
        ->take(Input::get("jtPageSize"))
        ->orderBy($search[0], $search[1])
        ->get();
      }
      return Response::json(
        array(
          "Result"      =>    "OK",
          "TotalRecordCount"  =>    $rows,
          "Records"     =>    $data
        )
      );
      break;

   };  
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the variables, no? You haven't told PHP what variable/object to do the `where()` to in your condition. The magic of Laravel's Eloquent (and a lot of other libraries) is that when you call its methods, it returns itself (the object) back so you can make another method call to it right away.

So when you do this:

```
$data = DB::table("ordens")
    ->select(...)
    ->where(...);
```

is the same as:

```
$data = DB::table("ordens");
$data = $data->select(...);
$data = $data->where(...);
```

But you are trying to do `->where(...)` right away after `if` condition. You need to tell PHP which object/variable you are trying to call the method from. Like this:

```
$num = Input::get("nro_orden");

$data = DB::table("ordens")
    ->select(array('*', DB::raw('SUM(cant_pend) as cant_pend'), DB::raw('SUM(importe) as importe')))
    ->where('cod_prov', '=', $my_cod);

if (Input::has('nro_orden')) {
    $data = $data->where('nro_orden', '=', $num);
}

$data = $data->groupBy('nro_orden')
    ->skip(Input::get("jtStartIndex"))
    ->take(Input::get("jtPageSize"))
    ->orderBy($search[0], $search[1])
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks Unnawut so much

Comment: You might still want to refine your question though before you get more downvotes. Try add the error messages that you got when you first tried out might help.

Comment: I tried your help and show this POST http://localhost/adpanel/public/getDataordenes/list?nro_orden=1400001948&jtStartIndex=0&jtPageSize=15&jtSorting=fecha%20DESC 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Show us your last error message from `app/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: Ah I missed one semicolon from my answer, now corrected. I hope you spotted that.

Comment: [2014-06-30 18:58:53] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)' in ...
And without CONDITION IF:
[2014-06-30 18:58:53] production.ERROR: exception 'Sym' with message 'syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)' in ....
[2014-06-30 18:59:44] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'syntax error, unexpected '$data' (T_VARIABLE)' in ...

Comment: Please check the lines before `if`. Are you missing any semicolons? Or append your question with your new code.

Comment: Semicolon before the IF condition generating all the errors, I corrected that and now works correctly. Really appreciate your help, your time and effort to reach the solution. A big hug